# Dependency Property on inherited class ignoring default value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, inheritance

When I write

```
public class A : Control
{
    static A()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(A), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(A)));
    }
}

public class B : A 
{
}
```

`A` shows its style correctly but `B` doesn't have `A`'s style
But if I inherit `Button` for example, inherited control displays as button correctly

Why does it work for `Button` but not for my control?

Comment: This should usually work. There's probably something you haven't shows us yet.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are running that line of code inside the constructor of your class A. When you instantiate class B, constructor of B will run and not A. You could try doing something like this:

```
public class A : Control
{
    static A()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(A), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(A)));
    }
}

public class B : A 
{
     static B : base()
     {
     }
}
```

Comment: `static B : base()` will not even compile. A static constructor can not call a base class constructor.